# Android: Can I Detect When a User Wants to Install an App and Before the Installation Begins?

Tags: android, installation, detect

I want to detect when the user installs an app which is not download at the Google Play market. But I wanted to detect it before the app is installed.

I know it can be detected when its installed on the device.
Someone mentioned that when the user chooses "install", the
intent.ACTION_PACKAGE action will generate something that I can detect.

Can I do it this way?!

Answer (score 0):

If you are building your own image based on AOSP, you can listen to `ACTION_VIEW` with mime type of `application/vnd.android.package-archive` or [`ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE) and intercept them before the `PackageManager`.

However, if you are asking about GMS-based images (which is what the majority of the OEMs use), where your app is a regular third-party app, then the short answer is you can't get notified *before* the package is installed. You can however listen to the [`ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED) broadcast and find out when the user has installed a new application *after* the installation has finished.

Comment: `if(Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE .equals(intent.getAction())){
                    Toast.makeText(context, "install1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } 
              else  if(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_INSTALL.equals(intent.getAction())){
                    Toast.makeText(context, "install2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } `

Comment: but it doesn't Toast the message

Comment: ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED is work but it is installed,i want to detect when it start install but not finished

Comment: As I said, in order to listen to `ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE` you have to be building your own system image, and have your app be a system app, or be signed with the same signature as the system image.